# undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails returns NoMethodError in Bookings#create  Showing /home/mwenyewe/TOP/Fullstack_Ruby_on_Rails/Ruby_on_Rails/flight-booker/app/views/bookings/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass when I try to submit the passenger details.
Here is my Booking new.html.erb

```rb
<%= form_with model: @booking do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :flight, 'Flight ID' %>
  <%= form.text_field :flight, value: @flight.id, readonly: true, disabled: true %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :flight_id, value: @flight.id %>
  
  <%= form.label :date, 'Date' %>
  <%= form.text_field :date, value: @flight.start, readonly: true, disabled: true %><br>

  <%= form.label :departure_airport, 'Departure Airport' %>
  <%= form.text_field :departure_airport, value: @flight.departure_airport.code, readonly: true, disabled: true %>
  
  <%= form.label :arrival_airport, 'Arrival Airport' %>
  <%= form.text_field :arrival_airport, value: @flight.arrival_airport.code, readonly: true, disabled: true %><br>

  <% @booking.passengers.each do |passenger| %>
    <%= form.fields_for :passengers_attributes, passenger do |p| %>
      <%= p.hidden_field :id, value: p.object.id %>

      <%= p.label :name %>
      <%= p.text_field :name %>
        
      <%= p.label :email %>
      <%= p.email_field :email %><br><br>  
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.submit %><br>
<% end %>
```

The first part of the form is supposed to show the flight details the passenger pick. The second form allows user to enter passenger details.
Here is my controller:

```rb
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
    @flight = Flight.find(params[:flight_id])
    params[:tickets].to_i.times{ @booking.passengers.build }
  end

  def create
    @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)

    if @booking.save
      redirect_to flights_path
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:flight_id, passengers_attributes: [:id, :name, :email])
  end
end
```

Here is the Flight index view which is supposed to send the flight_id:

```rb
<%= form_with url: new_booking_path, method: :get do |f| %>
      <% @found_flights.each do |flight| %>
        <%= f.radio_button :flight_id, flight.id %>
        <%= f.label "flight_#{flight.id}" do %>
        
          From: <%= flight.departure_airport.code %>
          To: <%= flight.arrival_airport.code %>
          Date: <%= flight.start.to_fs(:long) %>
          Tickets: <%= request.query_parameters[:flight][:tickets] %>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :tickets, value: request.query_parameters[:flight][:tickets] %>
      <% end %>
    <%= f.submit 'Select Flight' %>
    <% end %>
```

I have tried to follow the parameters being passed through but everything seem to be doing it's job. Even if the flight_id wasn't being passed it would display the flight details to the user.

Comment: @flight = Flight.find(params[:flight_id]). This code gets the id from the parameters sent from flight index not booking.

Comment: Not from booking_params method

Comment: Are you sure there is a value in params[:flight_id]? Because looking at your form it should be in the booking entity.

Comment: Everything looks correct, try using `binding.pry` in the new.html.erb to identify why your object is nil.

Comment: Yeah, I am sure. I printed it and it returned the flight.id

Comment: The error is after I have submitted the passenger details

Comment: Rails `find` method raises `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if the ID is not submitted or the record is missing. So the `@flight`variable should be set in the `new`action. Double-check that any code after doesn't reset it. It can happen in `params[:tickets].to_i.times{ @booking.passengers.build }`, it also can happen in the view itself before rendering the form.

Answer (score 0):

I found out my Models were bloated and were the culprits although I don't know how but I am yet to find out.
Here are my models before I edited them:

```rb
<---app/models/booking.rb--->
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :flight, class_name: 'Flight', foreign_key: 'flight_id'
  has_many :passengers, class_name: 'Passenger', foreign_key: 'booking_id'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :passengers
end

<---app/models/flight.rb--->
class Flight < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :departure_airport, class_name: "Airport", foreign_key: "departure_airport_id"
  belongs_to :arrival_airport, class_name: "Airport", foreign_key: "arrival_airport_id"
  has_many :bookings, class_name: "Booking", foreign_key: "flight_id"
end

<---app/models/passenger.rb--->
class Passenger < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :booking, class_name: 'Booking', foreign_key: 'booking_id'
end
```

Now here is after:

```rb
<---app/models/booking.rb--->
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :flight, class_name: 'Flight', foreign_key: 'flight_id'
  has_many :passengers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :passengers
end

<---app/models/flight.rb--->
class Flight < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :departure_airport, class_name: "Airport", foreign_key: "departure_airport_id"
  belongs_to :arrival_airport, class_name: "Airport", foreign_key: "arrival_airport_id"
  has_many :bookings
end

<---app/models/passenger.rb--->
class Passenger < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :booking
end
```

As you can see I trimmed it down trying to find the bug. I still don't know how it was causing the bug but I like my apps without bugs. I would be grateful if someone with experience could tell me what was causing the bug.